# React Native: Invariant Violation: Invalid argument passed as callback. Expected a function. Instead received: [object Object]

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to update booleans with setState onPress. Depending on which button pressed, other booleans will be set to false or respectively true.

Code:

```javascript
export default class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      isMeat: true,
      isVegan: false,
      isVegetarian: false,
    }
  }  

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.menuTop}>
          <MenuButton navigation = {this.props.navigation} />
          <Text style={styles.menuText}>Settings</Text>
        </View>
        <View style = {styles.body}>
            <Button title="make it vegan!"
                    style = {styles.vegan}
                    onPress = {()=> {
                      this.setState({isMeat : false}, {isVegan: true}, {isVegetarian: false})
                    }}
            >
              make it vegan!
            </Button>
            <Button title="vegetarian please"
                    style = {styles.vegetarian}
                    onPress = {()=> {
                      this.setState({isMeat : false}, {isVegan: false}, {isVegetarian: true})
                    }}
            >
              vegetarian please
            </Button>
            <Button title="meat me up, Scotty!"
                    style = {styles.meat}
                    onPress = {()=> {
                      this.setState({isMeat : true}, {isVegan: false}, {isVegetarian: false})
                    }}
            >
              meat me up, Scotty!
            </Button>
        </View>
    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When I press one of the buttons I get the error message:  `Invariant Violation: Invalid argument passed as callback. Expected a function. Instead received: [object Object]` but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's dig into this. The other answers are correct in showing how to fix your code but don't explain why they are correct. You said it happens when you hit the button, so it's related to `onPress`.

```
onPress = {()=> {
    this.setState({isMeat : false}, {isVegan: true}, {isVegetarian: false})
}}
```

This is what you have in the button, specifically, setState(...) passed inside of a thunk / arrow function. The thunk/arrow function is good—it matches the type required by `onPress` which is a function and runs `setState` when you press the button. So far, so good.

Now, let's take a look at `setState`'s docs in [React, specifically what arguments it takes](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). If you look below, it takes *two arguments*—an updater (the classical setState object) and a callback.

```
setState(updater[, callback])
```

Ok, let's look at what you have again, even more closely:

```
this.setState({isMeat : false}, {isVegan: true}, {isVegetarian: false})
```

So, if we compare what you wrote with what is in the docs, you've passed `{isMeat: false}` as the updater, `{isVegan: true}` as the optional callback, and `{isVegetarian: false}` as a third, completely unused argument.

`{isMeat: false}` is NOT a function, hence you're getting the message you see. THAT's why you're seeing the invariant violation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setState` to assign multiple properties at once, and avoid multiple calls like a previous answer suggested, like this:

```
this.setState({
       isMeat: false,
       isVegan: true,
       isVegetarian: false
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you're passing multiple objects into your setState() functions?

Try switching them out for single objects updating only the properties you want to change. For example:

```
<Button title="make it vegan!"
  style = {styles.vegan}
  onPress = {()=> {
  this.setState({isVegan: true})
  }}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this it works:

```
<Button title="make it vegan!"
                    style = {styles.vegan}
                    onPress = {()=> {
                      this.setState({isMeat : false})
                      this.setState({isVegetarian : false})
                      this.setState({isVegan : true})
                    }}
            >
              make it vegan!
            </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the error because I was not passing a callback to `OneSignal.promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse`

found it while reading the stacktrace